# Database for key value pairs

Tags: sql, database, mobile, key-value

Which data base is most appropriate for storing key/value pairs?
And the database should support mobile enviroment or devices.

Applications are intened to run on windows mobile and windows phone

Comment: should it be embedded like e.g. sqlite?

Comment: @hajo yes, it shud be embedded.

Comment: for android there is leveldb by google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no simple answer to this with so little information.
Take a google at "No SQL" or "Document Databases" - should find you what you need.

If you are after WP7 there are some good suggestions here http://nosql-database.org/

Comment: i ve heard that in android ther is such a feature for storing key/value pairs efficeintly than other dbs..

Comment: yes there is, and on iPhone (core data) and in html5 (http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) etc. We don't even know if you are writing native apps or html

Comment: its for native apps on windows mobile and windows phone